# install mysql using docker are they located in the same server

Tags: mysql, docker

I installed mysql8 using docker by following official guide [docker mysql getting started](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/docker-mysql-getting-started.html)

```
 docker run --name mysql8 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx -d mysql:8.0
```

And I noticed the following phenomena:

1. I didn't use volume `-v` in `docker run` command, but after stop and start, I can see that the database and data that I added are still there. (I found in tutorials that without volume specification data would be missing after restart container)
2. root user does not have `'%'` as allowed domain, but it can somehow login mysql server like this:

```
docker exec -it mysql8 mysql -uroot -p
```

is the host server somehow in the same domain as mysql server?

3. although I can login mysql in host by using root account, and I have a some.sql file in host `pwd` folder, but I cannot run `source some.sql` in mysql cli. I think it is because they are not in the same domain, and mysql does not see some.sql file inside its container.

Please help to explain the above 3 items. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I didn't use volume -v in docker run command, but after stop and start, I can see that the database and data that I added are still there. (I found in tutorials that without volume specification data would be missing after restart container)

Data will survive container restarts, but not its deletion and re-creation. A volume wouldn't be affected by it.

> is the host server somehow in the same domain as mysql server?

You are executing that command in the container, rather than on the host, so from MySQL server's perspective the connection is coming from `localhost`. You could use a `mysql` client installed on the host or in another container to make the connection and that wouldn't work.

> I think it is because they are not in the same domain

That's irrelevant.

> and mysql does not see some.sql file inside its container.

This is spot-on. The container is isolated from the host. It can't access its filesystem. That's the point of containerization: you want stuff to be running in isolation from the host and not affecting it.

You can either share a file or directory using a volume (`-v /some/dir/on/host:/some/dir/in/container`) or copy the file with `docker cp`.

Comment: Very clear, thanks